# Disable Multiple concurrent sessions for Same User in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: authentication, dynamics-crm-2011

Currently Dynamics CRM 2011 allows multiple concurrent sessions for same user (i.e. multiple employees can sign in with same user name in same time), I need to disable this so that CRM will sign out logged in user if other user signed in with same user credentials.

Is this doable?

Thank you.

Comment: Dynamics CRM is a web application. It is stateless and does not maintain sessions. On behalf of a single user multiple concurrent requests can be issued to the server, which is fine and should not be throttled.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this functionality exists out of the box in any version of CRM.